# OpenURI - 500 Internal Server Error on XML feed

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm trying to read Stanford ecorner XML:

```
open("http://ecorner.stanford.edu/RecentlyAdded.xml")
```

but am running into the following error message:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:277:in `open_http'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
    from (irb):65
    from :0
```

I believe, but I could be wrong, it's because I would need to be logged in to use the feed.

Any workaround I could use?

Comment: Are you sure that you weren't just hitting a temporary server problem? I can `lynx -dump -source http://ecorner.stanford.edu/RecentlyAdded.xml` without any problems.

Comment: @mu is too short, I think that's what it is. A 500-range is server-side problems. Authorization errors would be a 400-range error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of not being logged in you should get an HTTP response code of `401 Unauthorized` and not `500`. I tried to open the site in the browser, which works. Turns out their web server doesn't like missing user agents, so if you add that `open-uri` works:

```
>> require 'open-uri' 
#=> true
>> open("http://ecorner.stanford.edu/RecentlyAdded.xml", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby') 
#=> #<File:/var/folders/H9/H9qnar1yGZqBrWFGuTE0RU+++TI/-Tmp-/open-uri20110505-25566-zsc3pd-0>
```

Comment: I tried without and got the same 500 error as OP and adding `User-Agent` fixed it. A similar issue was also reported on ruby-talk for some other site, which is where I got the fix from.

Comment: Well, a 500 means their server messed up. If they didn't want you to see content because of a missing User-Agent string they should have denied access with a different code, probably a 400-range response. I suspect they have a misconfigured or broken host and the User-Agent is a red herring.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Or perhaps their code is doing something with the user agent (such as mangling the data to get around bugs) but they neglected to account for the "no `User-Agent`" case. So, `lynx -dump -source` will work because it sends a user agent but a request without a user agent causes their server to get upset, fall over, and catch fire.

Comment: @mu is too short, well, that would be a good hypothesis, except that I'd already found that it worked without a user-agent being defined. That's in my answer to this question.

Comment: Works great with User-Agent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://ecorner.stanford.edu/RecentlyAdded.xml'))
puts doc.search('title').map{ |n| n.text }

>> Recently Added STVP Entrepreneurship Corner Materials
>> STVP Entrepreneurship Corner
>> Podcast: Developing Products that Save Lives - Richard Scheller (Genentech)
>> Podcast: How to Build Instant Connections - Ori Brafman (Author)
>> Podcast: A New Vision for Capital Markets - Barry Silbert (SecondMarket)
>> Podcast: Effective Models for Sustainable Growth - Jennifer Morris (Conservation International)
```

Note that you got a 500-range error. That means their server is acting up, but is functional enough to admit the problem. If you got a 400-range error they'd be refusing you access to the content for some reason, so I doubt the problem is authentication or anything on your side.